Write files to delta table efficiently
I am writing data into delta table which is partitioned and dataframe size would be around 170 GB. How to write it to delta table efficiently?
Note : enabled AQE, shuffle partition auto and other AQE config also. I tried without using AQE and added shuffle partition number. I got better result using AQE. But AQE is taking more time to write. Most of the time is consuming in "AQEShuffle Read" part. any suggestion?
